# Show image if screen resolution is over?

Tags: html, css, image

I am looking for a way to show an image ONLY if screen resolution is higher than x,x for a webpage. The website it currently using only HTML/CSS, although I am open to ideas.

If this is possible any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the language/environment?

Comment: My apologies. This is HTML/CSS for a webpage.

Comment: for that maybe at first you need to learn a bit about media queries

http://www.broken-links.com/2012/07/13/using-media-queries-to-test-device-resolution/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For that, we usually use media queries**

```
// Set Defaults for Small displays like Mobile
.img { 
    display:none; // your image class or can be img tag
} 

// Desktop and landscape tablets more than 960 px
@media (min-width: 960px){
   .img { display: block; margin: 0 auto;} // your image class or can be img tag
}
```

if you're interested just have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/introduction-to-css-media-queries.html)

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand how media queries work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
.img
{
   display:none;
}
@media (min-width:800px) and (max-width:1200px)
{ 

 .img{display:block;}

}
```

you can visit this site for more information
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-cssqueries/