# Removing 'specific' images with media queries

Tags: html, css, image, media

I am looking for how to remove specific images with media queries. I am using HTML/CSS for a webpage.

Here is the code I currently have, which does not work (it was experimental):

```
@media (min-width:0px) and (max-width:1200px) {

LEVEL 1.png, level 6.png, http://placehold.it/160x600, http://placehold.it/100x100 {
display:none;
}

}
```

Any suggestions would be great, thanks.

Comment: Looking at the code, I see perhaps I need to rename the images to having no spaces and perhaps it will work. I'll let you all know how it goes.

Comment: you should add a id to img tag then in the css file use: `#imgid{display:none}`

Comment: Hmm, I tried removing the spaces, and it did infact work, however- the media query does not take effect, they get removed at all resolutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give the images a class and then in the media query:

```
.that-class-name {
  display: none;
}
```

Also, you should probably remove `min-width: 0`. I'm wondering if something less than `1200px` would be better for for `max-width` as well. That's very wide.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After doing it, while it did make the images disappear, it appears that the media query is not working for those images however - the images are no longer there at any resolution. I changed the media query to @media (max-width:1200px){

Comment: @user3227878 are you sure you're window is more than 1200px wide?

Comment: My window is 1920px wide.

Comment: @user3227878 there's your problem :)

Comment: On further observation it looks like two of the images disappeared, however two of them are working as intended, disappearing when the change the browser size to under 1200px. Here is the code:
        
        @media (max-width:1200px){
 
        .imagea {
 display:none;
 }
 
 .imageb {
 display:none;
 }
 
 .imagec {
 display:none;
 }
 
 .imaged {
 display:none;
 }
 
 }

Comment: That's really redundant. Just give them the same classname. Why repeat yourself!?

Comment: I didn't know you could use the same class name for more than one image. I'm still fairly new to coding. This is what I have now, but still the same issue: two images disappearing completely, two images working as intended.

@media (max-width:1199px){
 
    .imagea {
 display:none;
 }
 
 }

(I've checked that they have the same class-names).

Comment: I figured out why two were disappearing. It was an error with re-naming the original files while trying another method.

Thanks a heap for your help!

Comment: @user3227878 No problem. Classes are meant for reuse. It is id's that must be unique. Imagine if you had to employees with the same employee id. That would be bad for obvious reasons (how would you know which person did what). Their class is "employee" that's reusable because they're both employees! This same logic goes for html.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have to add a class inside the your media query

```
@media (min-width:0px) and (max-width:1200px)
   .img { display: none; margin: 0 auto;} // your image class or can be img tag
}
```

and just now i answered the same question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21360304/3082414)